# Quasar CLI VUE instance

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, quasar-framework, quasar

Help me solve with the problem please.
I am using jquery and jquery-ui to implement drag & drop in QASAR CLI.
But I ran into the fact that I cannot access the vue instance from jquery function events, since "this" no longer belongs to Vue, but refers to the selector element. Tell me how I can refer directly to the vue instance as it could be done in cdn version. There you could just give the name app = new Vue ... And then use it as app.data.variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is more javascript question, than quasar/vue/jquery. You can easily set value of `this` by a `bind` function

```
let someFunction = function () {
  console.log(this);
}

someFunction();

const obj = { 'test': 123 };

someFunction = someFunction.bind(obj);

someFunction();
```

[image]

Same thing applies to jquery function handlers. I guess you could pass your instance instead of `obj`

```
$(window).ready(function () {
  console.log(this);
}.bind(obj));
```